# How can i seed with faker a random id or null in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, seeding, faker

I am trying to seed a parent_id column with a random id of the same table or let it be null.

This i thought it will work:

```
...
'parent_id' => $faker->boolean() ? Page::all()->random()->id : null,
...
```

But i get the following error:

```
  You requested 1 items, but there are only 0 items available.
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Update1:

Using pseudoanime answer i tried the flowing :

```
$factory->define(Page::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
...
    $parent_id = null;
...
    $has_parent = $faker->boolean(50);
    Log::debug('$has_parent' . $has_parent);
    if ($has_parent) {
        $parents = Page::all();
        Log::debug('$parents' . count($parents));

        if ($parents->isEmpty()) {
            Log::debug('isEmpty');

            $parent_id = null;
        } else {
            Log::debug('$parents->random()' . print_r($parents->random(), true));
            $parent_id = $parents->random()->id;
        }
    }

    return [
...

        'parent_id' => $parent_id,
...
    ];
}
```

From what i can see every time it is run `Page::all();` return empty.
Any idea why that is?

Comment: `Page::all()` returns 0 results, so you cannot select 1 random

Comment: I get that this is the reason for the error but how can i generate the random parent_id otherwise?

Comment: By first creating (seeding) pages to choose from?

Comment: This is a great question.  Should not be down voted.  If you have a form field that is optional - very common! - it may get populated with, say, a user's ID or project's ID or it may be null.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
'parent_id' => $faker->boolean(50) ? Page::orderByRaw('RAND()')->first()->id : null,
```

Essentially we're saying, order by random, get the first and then get it's id.

`boolean(50)` should give you a 50% chance of true, so 50% false.

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  function rand() does not exist                             
  LINE 1: select * from "pages" order by RAND() limit 1`

Comment: Try `orderByRaw` I had `orderbyRaw`

Comment: i also tried `$faker->boolean(50) ? Page::inRandomOrder()->get()->first()->id : null,` but i get `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object  `

Answer (score 9):

Given "Parent" as the parent model, I do this:

1. first seed the Parent;
2. seed the Child table using this code in the factory:

`'parent_id' => $faker->optional()->randomElement(App\Parent::all()->pluck('id'))`

It works because faker's *randomElement()* takes an array which you populate with all and only the *'id'* values of the parent table.

The *optional()* faker's modifier does or doesn't put a NULL in the *parent_id* at random. As stated in [faker's GitHub](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#modifiers), ***optional() sometimes bypasses the provider to return a default value instead (which defaults to NULL)***.
You can also specify the probability of receiving the default value and the default value to return.

NB: you can't do anything if the Parent table isn't seeded. If so, consider the answer of dlnsk.

Answer (score 6):

```
$factory->define(Page::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    $ids = Page::pluck('id')->toArray();

    return [
        'parent_id' = empty($ids) ? null : $faker->optional(0.9, null)->randomElement($ids);  // 10% chance of null
    ];
});
```

Comment: our amazing man thanks a lot all what i need is the method optional >>>> here is the full doc of this method https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/issues/1227

Answer (score 0):

Your error is happening because your query to page (page:all()->random()) returns  no results.

Basically your issue is that you care trying to create a parent to a page before a page is even created.

You can should try something like check if the Page::all() returns a non empty collection, if yes, then get a random element from there, if not, create a new element.

I personally would do something like create a class for null parent element & one that would do null & non-empty parent element.

```
$factory->defineAs(Page::class, 'ParentPage', function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        //the rest of your elements here
        'parent_id' => null
    ];
});

$factory->defineAs(Page::class, 'page', function (Faker $faker) {
    $has_parent = $faker->boolean();
    if($has_parent) {
        $parents = Page::all();
        if($parents->isEmpty()) {
            $parent_id = factory(Page::class, 'ParentPage')->create()->id;
        } else {
            $parent_id = $parents->random()->id;
        }
    }
    return [
        //the rest of your elements here
        'parent_id' => $has_parent? $parent_id : null
    ];
});
```

You can create regular pages like `factory(Page::class, 'page')->times(50)->create();` in your seeder

The code above is not tested, but the logic should be correct.

Comment: starting from your code i tested it like this: 
   ` $parent_id = null; $has_parent = $faker->boolean();
    if ($has_parent) {
        $parents = Page::all();
        if (!$parents->isEmpty()) {
            $parent_id = Page::all()->random()->id;
        }
    }

    return [
        'parent_id' => $parent_id,]`  But although it runs with no error it does not generate any parent_id.

Comment: I just tried the code on my machine & it's generating parent_ids for me, I've updated the code to match my exact code, can you try now?

Comment: @vlad, you haven't changed the function arguments, you need to define two model factory functions and update the function signatures to $factory->defineAs(Page::class, 'ParentPage', function (Faker $faker) and $factory->defineAs(Page::class, 'page', function (Faker $faker) respectively. Please check my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function run()
    {
        factory(\App\Comment::class, 30)->make()->each(function ($comment){
            $comments = Comment::all();
            if ($comments->count() == 0) {
                $comment->parent = null;
            } else {
                $rand = random_int(1, $comments->count());
                if ($rand >= 2 && $rand <= 5){
                    $comment->parent = null;
                }elseif ($rand >= 12 && $rand <=17){
                    $comment->parent = null;
                }elseif ($rand >= 22 && $rand <= 27){
                    $comment->parent = null;
                }else{
                    $comment->parent = $rand;
                }
            }
            $comment->save();
        });
    }
```